# Encoding POSTGRES with copy command

Tags: postgresql, psql

i am with a problem with `postgres`. I am doing copy command with a `csv` but when i going to see a data into database it is wrong, like: `H├®di ├Üjv├íri` and should be: `Hédi Újvári`....

I have already used several `enconding` but none working. I have used `utf8`, `latin 8`, `latin 1`, `latin 9`, `win 1252`...

My query is like this:

```
\COPY “test” (name) FROM 'C:\tmp\1.csv’ DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER encoding  ‘LATIN9’;
```

Someone knows how fix it ?

Comment: What is the encoding of the data in the CSV file?

Comment: @LutzHorn, i dont know, how i do see it?

Comment: @LutzHorn i export it as UTF8

Comment: Then use `UTF-8`.

Comment: I use, but it not working.. :(

Comment: are you sure the **data** is not encoded properly?... it could be the **viewer** that is not displaying it as you would expect